# Oracle: How to setup a database backup to a network drive

Tags: oracle, backup

Oracle database 11g. What is the easiest way to set up a full nightly database backup to a network drive (ie drive on another computer)?

Answer (score 1):

[Read the backup and recovery guide.](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db111/portal.portal_db?selected=4&frame=#backup_and_recovery)

Don't just backup... Make sure you test your backup, regularly!!

Comment: While this is true it doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Grid Control setup the easiest way would be to use the web interface.  The interface allows you to specify a unc path (\computer\share name).  You will have to create a share on the remote computer.

If you don't have Grid Control you can create a script that uses [RMAN](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/backup.111/b28270/toc.htm).  If you need script specifics it would be helpful to know what OS your database is on.

Answer (score 0):

You need a backup strategy.  Once you have defined that you will see what options are available to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

mount the network drive, use rman to fully backup the db to the network drive.  Rman can do it hot.  Another method is to export full but you'll have to flush all writes and put the db into restricted mode so no user can make changes while you export to get a full consistent backup.